# SQL Server : MERGE statement, compare with select data instead of table data

Tags: node.js, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

```
merge into item_set TARGET
using (select  '545934' as product_id_01, 4 as set_sort_no, 15 as article_id,
'Note for this item set' as note, 0 as is_deleted) as SOURCE
    on TARGET.set_sort_no = SOURCE.set_sort_no and TARGET.product_id_01 = SOURCE.product_id_01

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET TARGET.article_id = SOURCE.article_id,
            TARGET.note = SOURCE.note,
            TARGET.is_deleted = SOURCE.is_deleted,
            TARGET.version = TARGET.version

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (product_id_01, set_sort_no, article_id, note, is_deleted, version)
    VALUES (SOURCE.product_id_01, SOURCE.set_sort_no, SOURCE.article_id, SOURCE.note, SOURCE.is_deleted, 3);
```

I have a query as shown above, I would like to know if it is possible to use multiple values(array of values) instead of the below statement from the query without using a table

```
(select  
     '545934' as product_id_01, 
     4 as set_sort_no, 15 as article_id,
     'Note for this item set' as note, 0 as is_deleted) as SOURCE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You can use a VALUE table constructor to create a set of rows in `using (..)`

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for @Serg

Answer (score 0):

No.MS SQL Server was not designed to support arrays